# Delete mysql row with 2 of 3 fields specified?

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I'm trying to construct a simple delete statement in mysql and can't seem to get it right. I want to be able to delete a row using just the `x` and `y` fields without specifying the description field.

The table looks like this:

```
+------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| x                | y                 | description |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|  52.847202686351 | -113.833362226293 |             |
| 52.6810078148914 |  -113.65208781223 |             |
| 52.7625225559979 | -113.937732343481 |             |
| 52.8985943615787 | -113.415881757543 |             |
| 53.0969562533962 | -113.479053144262 | millet      |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: DELETE FROM gps2 WHERE 'x' = '53.0969562533962' AND 'y' = '-113.479053144262'

Comment: Seems fine. What error did you get

Comment: also are `x` and `y` defined as floats?

Comment: just a query ok, 0 rows affected.  it's not matching it and my guess was that i had to be more specific (Specify the description field) but the way i'll be using it isn't going to be able to provide more than the x and y fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by imprecision of the `float` data type. Floats are notoriously difficult to use with exact comparisons. You might be better off storing this data as `decimal` type?

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY x DECIMAL(15,12);
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY y DECIMAL(15,12);
```